# npm install @types/jquery leads to Invalid name: "@types/jquery"

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, windows-10

```
npm install @types/jquery
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "@types/jquery"
npm ERR! node v7.5.0
npm ERR! npm  v4.1.2

npm ERR! Invalid name: "@types/jquery"
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     T:\...\npm-debug.log
```

Most people on Stack Overflow and GitHub suggest upgrading Node if a suchlike error occurs, but as you can see in the output: **Node already is the latest version** (Node 4 and Node 6.9 did not work as well).

Thus I guess it has something to do with an interaction of Windows 10 and certain settings on this machine (because other Windows 10 machines are not affected).

Installing arbitrary unscoped packages works without any problems on the machine while `npm install @types/jquery` does not.

Comment: Might have something to do with that stray `T:` drive?

Comment: Until the end of the weekend I have no access to the machine. I will test if this is the reason. Why do you think `T:` might be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
I found a similar thing answered on this page:

> https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/13986

In summary the error seems to be due to that a new installation of node/npm does not clean all old files that then gets in the way for the new installation.

I found that a reinstall with the command:

> npm install -g npm@latest

helped me.

Comment: Not helpful for me